Texture objects for doubles on a cuArray
I have a similar need for this question. The only difference is, I need to do this on a cuArray (because I want to use cudaAddressModeWrap), instead of a normal device storage.
So, I tried this:
$ cat doubletexture.cu
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

static __inline__ __device__ double fetch_double(uint2 p){
    return __hiloint2double(p.y, p.x);
}

#define gpuErrchk(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, const char *file, int line, bool abort=true)
{
   if (code != cudaSuccess)
   {
      fprintf(stderr,"GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
      if (abort) exit(code);
   }
}
__global__ void my_print(cudaTextureObject_t texObject)
{
    uint2 rval = tex1Dfetch<uint2>(texObject, 0.4);
    double dval = fetch_double(rval);
    printf("%f\n", dval);
}

int main()
{
    double i = 0.35;
    int numel = 10;

    std::vector<double> h_data(numel, i);
    double* d_data;
    cudaMalloc(&d_data,numel*sizeof(double));
    cudaMemcpy((void*)d_data, &h_data[0],
               numel*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    cudaTextureDesc td{};
    td.filterMode = cudaFilterModePoint;
    td.addressMode[0] = cudaAddressModeClamp;
    td.readMode = cudaReadModeElementType;

    cudaArray_t cArray;
    cudaChannelFormatDesc channelDesc =
      cudaCreateChannelDesc(32,32,0,0,cudaChannelFormatKindUnsigned);
    cudaMallocArray(&cArray,&channelDesc,numel,0);

    cudaResourceDesc resDesc;
    resDesc.resType = cudaResourceTypeArray;
    resDesc.res.array.array = cArray;

    cudaTextureObject_t texObject;
    gpuErrchk(cudaCreateTextureObject(&texObject, &resDesc, &td, NULL));

    cudaMemcpyToArray(cArray,0,0,d_data,numel*sizeof(double),
                      cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice);

    my_print<<<1,1>>>(texObject);
    gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
    return 0;
}

I have tried using different address modes, or filter modes, but the result is always zero. Where is it wrong?

tex1Dfetch is not the correct API to use when the underlying resource is a cudaArray. See here: "fetches from the region of linear memory ..."  Note in the immediately following API description for tex1D: "fetches from the CUDA array ..."  That is an important distinction.

I haven't studied your code carefully, but making that single change (tex1Dfetch -> tex1D) causes the kernel to print 0.35, which seems to be what you're after.  Also note that cudaMemcpyToArray is deprecated.

@RobertCrovella Thank you! problem solved! And I also noticed the deprecated warning.


… only difference is, I need to do this on a cuArray

Then you need to use a different texture fetch API within the kernel. tex1Dfetch is used for linear memory based texture reads. tex1D is used for array based texture reads.
As indicated in comments, if you make that change in the kernel, the code should work correctly.

Thank you! I totally forget this. Another thing is, by this method, the filter mode can only be cudaFilterModePoint, does this means that one can not realize linear interpolation in double precision?

Obviously you can’t do interpolation on doubles with the filtering hardware. You are reading integers, there is no way to perform correct interpolation on the individual upper and lower words of a float64 as integers. The filtering hardware can do limited accuracy interpolation (8 or 10 bits IIRC) on 32 bit data only. You will have to think of another way to do this

For example, maybe I can set two float instead of uint2, calculate the linear interpolation, and then find a way to construct the correct double result from the two float results. Is it possible to do this?
